# How to declare range as Path?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a solution for my code, I need a "MyDir" reads Path from Sheet1.Range("A1"). This is the code that loads the image from "MyDir" + image name, but it only works if you put in the code for MyDir for example: *C:\Users\Me\Desktop*. But I do not want that, I want to *C:\Users\Me\Desktop* read from `Sheet1.Range("A1")`, can someone help me with this code:

```
Dim MyDir As Range
Set MyDir = Sheet1.Range("A1")
If Len(Dir("MyDir" & TextBox1.Text & ".jpg")) > 0 Then
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("MyDir" & TextBox1.Text & ".jpg")
Else
    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("")
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the quotes around `MyDir`?

Comment: yes, quotes go if you want to put C:\Users\Me\Desktop\

Comment: You don't need the quotes as you have assigned the path to the variable `MyDir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the quotes around `MyDir`.

I also test for the existence of the file using `Dir() <> ""`

Here my image is called "code_pic.jpg".

```
Sub image()

    Dim MyDir As Range
    Set MyDir = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    If Dir(MyDir) <> "" Then
        Set Sheet1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(MyDir & "\code_pic.jpg")
    Else
        Set Sheet1.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable MyDir is in quotes.

```
Sub test()

Dim fullpath_and_name As String

Dim MyDir As Range

Set MyDir = Sheet1.Range("A1")

fullpath_and_name = MyDir & "\" & "test.bmp"

Debug.Print Dir(fullpath_and_name)

If Len(Dir(MyDir & "\" & "test.bmp")) > 0 Then

  Image1 = LoadPicture(MyDir & "\" & "test.bmp")

Else

Image1 = LoadPicture("")

End If

End Sub
```

I was unable to get the Image1.Picture to work, but the Len(...) part of the code *does* work, so the rest is just reading the picture.

Comment: You need to specify that you want the `picture` property of `Image1`, namely `Image1.Picture`